# SharePoint 2013 - Save Conflict

Tags: 2013, error, save

I have a problem Edit an item in a list.

After I insert much data it reports an error below:

> Save Conflict  Those conflict with your changes made ​​concurrently by
>   another user. If you want your changes to be applied, click Back in
>   your Web browser, refresh the page, and resubmit your changes.

I do not know what would be the problem, I had two hypotheses:

1. This error can be going to be a long time in the form and edit
   SharePoint asks to update. This makes me lose a lot of time;
2. Having something or updating the workflow item I'm editing and the
   conflict happens. MAS contains no JQuery or Workflow or other
   updating the item.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem.
This might help you. 
http://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/sharepoint-error-save-conflict-your-changes-conflict-with-those-made-concurrently-by-another-user/

Comment: Please include the gist of your post incase the link dies one day. Other readers: basically re-get the item by its ID.

Answer (score 0):

The link provided by Augusto Presotto was VERY helpful.
http://adrianhenke.wordpress.com/2010/08/20/sharepoint-error-save-conflict-your-changes-conflict-with-those-made-concurrently-by-another-user/

Essentially, the SaveConflict error indicates the item was changed since the item was initially loaded and the update attempt was made.

The link provides this very useful snippet of code to help with this.  You can run the function right before making your item updates:

```
/// <summary>
/// Reload a list item from scratch
/// </summary>
/// <param name="item">The list item</param>
/// <remarks>
/// Useful to avoid save conflicts
/// </remarks>
/// <returns></returns>
public static SPListItem ReloadListItem(SPListItem item)
{
    if (item == null)
        return null;

    return item.ParentList.GetItemByUniqueId(item.UniqueId);
}
```

Example Usage:

```
item=ReloadListItem(item);
item["Title"]="Just reloaded the item prior to update.";
item.Update();
```